# How to return return pointer from C++ dll function to C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I have two extern function that one of them is return C++ pointer another is print ip and port, when i want to use on C# , parameters pass' successfully than print port and ip after that when i called second function,it dont print address correctly.

Cpp

```cpp
Obj* x_create_obj_ip_port(const char* ip, int port) {
    Obj* obj = new Obj();
    cout << ip << endl;
    obj->ip = (char*)ip;
    cout << obj->ip << endl;
    obj->port = 102;

    return obj;
}

Obj::Obj() {
    this->counter = 0;
    this->ip = (char*)"";
    this->port = 0;
    this->something = (char*)"";
    this->cid = false;
    this->gi = false;
    this->report = false;
    this->signals_counter = 0;
    this->Tada = nullptr;
    
}

void print_ip(Obj* obj) {
    cout << "object ip " <<obj->ip << endl;
    cout << "Object port " << obj->port << endl;
    //cout << "connection ip " << obj->connection->ip << endl;
}
```

And C# side

```cs
[DllImport(DllPath.path, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr x_create_obj_ip_port(string ip, int port);

[DllImport(DllPath.path, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void print_ip(IntPtr self);

IntPtr _con = new IntPtr();
           
_con = x_create_obj_ip_port("10.6.35.228", 102);

print_ip(_con);
```

And log is like below:

[image]

Comment: it's just a pointer to some memory ... obviously outside x_create_obj_ip_port it would not be valid as marshaler will free it

Comment: I understand nothing from his writing. Can somebody please translate it into English please?

Comment: @snr i simplified the text, you could read again

Comment: You should not be modifying C# `string` via C++ unmanaged code. You can marshal it to an `HGlobal` if you want, or use `StringBuilder`

Comment: @SerhanErkovan That's still not yet proper english. https://www.deepl.com/translator may help you, or https://www.antidote.info/en?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured your problem.

In x_create_obj_ip_port, you set obj->ip with a *pointer* on the parameter ip. I'm no expert in C# but I'm pretty sure the string "10.6.35.228" gets deleted right after the call, meaning now obj->ip points on nothing, explaining why print_ip prints garbage.

If you want to keep the content of a parameter in your struct for later use, you should **copy** it and not just save the pointer on it since anyone may delete it.

In other words, you may change your object so the ip is a table containing the actual ip and not just a pointer. This way, you can 'fill' the ip when calling x_create_obj_ip_port

```
class Obj {
  // ...
  // was const char *ip;
  char ip[128];
  // ...
}
```

```
#include <string.h>

Obj* x_create_obj_ip_port(const char* ip, int port) {
    // ...
    strncpy(this->ip, ip, sizeof(this->ip)); // deep copy of source ip
    // ...
}
```